# Azure SQL Database Active Directory password authentication using powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, paas

I am trying to login in Azure SQL active password authentication using cloudhsell
below is the error I am facing mentioned in the screen shot.I am not able to understand is this the authentication issue or syntax issue in my script.

`$cxn.open` will open the connection but before that only I am facing issue.

After that I need to exectue the below commands

```
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$cxn.Close()
```

Objective is to login to Azure SQL using active password auth and write some SQL query and close the connection.This thing I need to do in devops inline script task but it is falling in cloudshell itself.

Error - detail mentioned in the below diagram, please let me know how to correct it.

[image]

Kindly let me know is there any other script is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix all your issues, but there is a syntax error there. 
In your connection string you put authentication="Azure Active Directory""
that is a syntax error because your double quote actually ends the string... 
get rid of the "" around the azure active directory. like. authentication=Azure Active Directory";
that would at least get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: Hi Alphaz I tried your method but in the next line I got a same error.

PS /home/anuj> $cxnString1="Server=tcp:bdasqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=BDAZDB01;Persist Security Info=False;
>> User ID=$login ;Password=$Password ;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication= Active Directory Password";



PS /home/anuj> $cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString1)

Errror - New-Object: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Keyword not supported: 'authentication'."
PS /home/anuj> $cxn.Open()

Comment: Unfortunately, It appears as though because you're using cloudshell, .net core library for sqlclient in the cloud shell likely isn't a version that supports the authentication parameter yet. they released a .net core sqlclient library that support this, bu that version is not deployed in the platform you are trying to use. if you have to use this platform, it looks like you will be forced to use a different method like Token authentication: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-database-token-based-authentication-with-powershell/ba-p/369078

Comment: Hi Alphaz thanks for the article , I also gone through same article, Unfortunately I am from the developer team, so Client doesn't provide the access for creating the New app registration in the Active directory. So is there any other way to automate this process, However I am chasing my client to provide the access for doing this task.

Comment: Could you please let me know which minimum permission is required in order to follow the steps given in link.

Comment: Here's a pretty complete example from start to finish for azure side and client side:
https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/06/06/ConnectToAzureSqlDatabaseByObtainingATokenFromAzureActiveDirectoryAad/

Comment: Hi Alphaz above links are very useful thanks this answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient